# RegEx: Getting multiple strings python

Tags: python, regex, markdown

I am working on a markdown interpreter in python.
I currently have problems with implementing links.
How can I look for multiple values inside a string with the Python regex module ?
My code:

```py
links = re.findall("[[^]]([^])", "Hello [World](example.com) Hello [Mars](example.org)")
```

My desired result should be

```py
[["World", "example.com"], ["Mars", "example.org]]
```

Comment: If this is something you actually want to run in production, there's a well-established [Python markdown library](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown) that's [available in pip as `Markdown`](https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
links = re.findall("\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)", "Hello [World](example.com) Hello [Mars](example.org)")
links = map(list,links)
print(list(links))
```

Output:

```
[['World', 'example.com'], ['Mars', 'example.org']]
```

Comment: `\w.+?` is a relatively weird option to use for the captured portion - it'd probably be better to just use `.+?` without the `\w`. The `\w` prefix would arbitrarily require the captured text to start with a letter, number, or underscore... and `[!!foo](www.example.com)` is a perfectly valid Markdown link that wouldn't match it.

Comment: This still won't work correctly for various corner cases. A better solution is to not use regular expressions at all.